# Getting raw html but not processed?

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I am using jQuery and AngularJS together.
An angular module process the document and binds values to the elements

```
<div id="theElement">{{name}}</div>
```

After document load and compiling we get:

```
<div id="theElement" class="ng-binding">something</div>
```

With the code $("#theElement").html() I have the following result:

```
<div id="theElement" class="ng-binding">something</div>
```

but I need to $("#theElement").SomeMethod() to get the same raw html not compiled html like below line:

```
<div id="theElement">{{name}}</div>
```

I there any jQuery or angular or tricky method to get raw html?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way is to pull the source from the server and then parse it with jquery like this:

```
$http.get("/path/to/page.html").success(function(data, status){
    var x = $("#theElement").html();
});
```

Comment: I have to obtain the not compiled source html markup from the current document at client. fetching entire or partially from the server is not a good idea and is not applicable for me.

Comment: I know that its a quite dirty way, but I'm nut sure if there is a nother one ;)